# What's up with 'ubī'?

Tags: etymology

Just noticed, with respect to [this question about 'which' and the five 'wh-' question words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/554646/why-isnt-the-word-which-one-of-the-5-wh-question-words/), that there's kind of a similar but reverse sort of situation in Latin.

It looks like of all the corresponding question words in Latin, **they are all 'qu-' words except for one**, the one corresponding to 'where', namely 'ubī'

'Ubī' stands out like a sore thumb. Where could that possibly have come from? *All* the other romance languages derive their 'where' from Latin.

But *all* the other IE families have a 'qu-' cognate word.  Slovak has 'kde', English 'where', Irish 'ca bhfuil', Iranian 'koja', Hindi 'jahã'.

So, what's up with 'ubī'? Where did it come from? Did Oscan-Umbrian have a cognate to 'ubī' or to a 'qu-' word?

Comment: Cf. *unde* "whence", *ut* "how". It may be related to the u in *ullus, usquam*, etc.

Comment: It is "kojãst". And "kojãst" means "where is". "kojã" is equivalent to "where".

Comment: @AliNikzad fixed

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It used to be! At some point, the word seems to have been **cubi*, as seen in compounds like *alicubi* "somewhere", *nēcubi* "not anywhere", *sīcubi* "if anywhere"; this came from the same root as *quis* and such, with the usual *qu* > *c* before *u*. (Compare *aliquis*.)

But at some point, it lost its initial C; re-analysis of *nē-cubi* as *nec-ubi* may have been involved, and/or the influence of *ibi* "there" (which comes from the root of *is* "he" with the same suffix). The details aren't entirely clear, just that it must have happened at some point in the language's history.

Comment: Any idea about the '-bi' part?

Comment: @Mitch I believe it's from PIE *-dʰi, cognate with Greek -θι.

Comment: And does PIE *-dʰi have any special meaning?

Comment: @Mitch "Where", or something like that.

Comment: Not that it's relevant to Latin, but any clue as to cognates of *-dʰi in other IE?

Comment: Excellent...thanks. Sometimes there's just no knowing the pregistory but this seems to work out pretty well (the loss of 'c' here).

Answer (score 10):

Draconis said everything there is to say about the loss of the **kʷ* AFAIK, but I spent €250 on an etymological dictionary of Latin a while back so I want to expand on the *-bi* part.

According to De Vaan's *Etymological Dictionary of Latin and the other Italic languages*, *ubī* can theoretically reflect either **kʷubʰei* or **kʷudʰei*. **-bʰi* would be a PIE instrumental ending, whereas **-dʰei* would be an Italic innovation for **kʷudʰe* 'where', which is reflected in Indo-Iranian (Skt. *kúha*, OAv. *kudā* 'where') and Slavic (*kьde* 'whenever, anywhere'). In view of the latter correspondence, De Vaan considers a Proto-Italic preform **kʷuþei* to be more likely (I don't think **kʷu* would still be **kʷu* in Proto-Italic, though; the boukólos rule should have eliminated the labialisation earlier than that). He finally notes that Hittite *ku-wa-pi* 'where, when' is attested, which reflects PIE **kʷó-bʰi* (that is, with the instrumental ending).

De Vaan doesn't mention it, but *-dʰe ~ *-dʰi* is a locative particle reflected in Greek as -θε or -θι, as Draconis mentioned, which shows up e.g. in Greek πόθι 'where' (which, however, has **kʷos* in the o-grade, like the Hittite; PIE **bʰ* would have become Gk. φ, though, so it can't continue the instrumental).

The Sabellic languages do have attested cognates of *ubi*, with the expected *p* at the front: Oscan **puf** and Umbrian **pufe**. Like the Latin, they could theoretically reflect either **kʷubʰei* or **kʷudʰei*.

(Annoyingly, the disappearance of the initial *c-* in Latin isn't even remarked on.)

Comment: Excellent..thanks